# Power Automate solution import breaks

Tags: power-automate

When importing large managed solution to target environment, wizard breaks on last step "Import" with message "Managed solution cannot be imported - Sorry, there's been a disconnect".

Clearing cookies, guest/incognito mode does not help.. other (created new for testing purpose) managed solution can be imported successfully.

This is rather new behavior since Microsoft is updating Power Automate portal.

Answer (score 0):

When contacted Microsoft support, they provided explanation:

> [we] noticed that it is being caused by a new feature that displays all environment variables on solution import in the solution import panel, as well as pipelines. After further investigation, we have determined that if the number of environment variables exceeds 50, the system will begin to crash.
>
> [..] add the following query string parameter to disable the feature to the environment URL:
>
> ?powerappsConnections.enableShowAllEnvVariablesOnImport=false

Once added, import works flawlessly - as before.